# SQL Server 2008 'RECONFIGURE' doesn't work for 'sp_configure filestream_access_level' on Windows 8

Tags: sql-server-2008

Okay, this is strange.

I installed Windows 8 and SQL Server 2008. The database I am working with has FileStream enabled and so I need to enable FileStream. And so, I did:

```
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2
RECONFIGURE
```

It didn't work.

So I tried using the UI in SQL Server Management Studio. Like this:

[image: Configured values]

Notice under configured value it is displaying "full access"

And under "running values":

[image: Running values]

And notice under "running values" it is displaying "disabled".

So I did:

1. Ran `RECONFIGURE`, it returns *Command(s) completed successfully*. Didn't work.
2. Restart SQL Server 2008. Didn't work.
3. Restart machine. Didn't work as well.

Now I wonder if I `RECONFIGURE` is broken or my UI is broken. So I tried changing `Default Language` to `UK - English` and ran `RECONFIGURE`. It worked! The language changed to UK under "running values".

So I guess the problem is Filestream access changes didn't get applied. But why?

I am running Windows 8 64 bit and this version of SQL Server:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64)   Jul  9 2008 14:17:44   
Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) 
  on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[filestream access level Server Configuration Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645956.aspx):

> Before this option has any effect, the Windows administration settings for FILESTREAM must be enabled. You can enable these settings when you install SQL Server or by using SQL Server Configuration Manager.